# Finding the carrier concentration of semiconductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

> Silicon (4 valence electrons) can be doped with arsenic (5 valence
>   electrons) to make an n-type semiconductor. Assuming 1 in every 15
>   million silicon atoms is replaced with arsenic, calculate the carrier
>   concentration, n, of the semiconductor.
>
> [Density of silicon = 2.33 g/cm3. Molar mass of silicon = 28.1 g
>   mol–1.]

Comment: I'm not even sure where to start with this...

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is the number of charge carriers per $cm^3$ of the semi conductor dopped. Find out the number of atoms present in a $cm^3$ of Si atom present, using the molar mass and density of the Si atom. Dividing it by 15 million gives number of Arsenic atom dopped. One Arsenic atom provides a single carrier. Thus, number of Arsenic atom dopped per $cm^3$ gives the carrier concentration.